# Pandas dataframe (getting one value without the index)

Tags: python, pandas

From a pandas dataframe, I want just the value and not the index.

```
state_dist = df[df['candidate'] == 'Don Young']['state_dist']
```

Returns:

```
    9    AK-00
Name: state_dist, dtype: object
```

Adding .to_string()

```
state_dist = df[df['candidate'] == 'Don Young']['state_dist'].to_string()
```

Returns:

```
'9    AK-00'
```

I do not want to loop, how can I just get:

```
'AK-00'
```

Comment: use `.to_string(index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) for the method you are using:

```
state_dist = df[df['candidate'] == 'Don Young']['state_dist'].to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: would be better to not chain the indexers: `df.loc[df['candidate'] == 'Don Young', 'state_dist']` <----- that will return a scalar

Answer (score -1):

If it is always one row, or the value that you are looking for is repeated after the filter, you can add [0] after your code and it would give you the value you are looking for:

```
state_dist = df[df['candidate'] == 'Don Young']['state_dist'][0]
```